# Planarity conditions for Planar 1-in-3 SAT

Tags: np-complete, reductions, satisfiability, 3-sat

**Planar 3SAT** is NP-complete. A planar 3SAT instance is a 3SAT instance for which the graph built using the following rules is planar:

1. add a vertex for every $x_i$ and $\bar{x_i}$
2. add a vertex for every clause $C_j$
3. add an edge for every $(x_i,\bar{x_i})$ pair
4. add an edge from vertex $x_i$ (or $\bar{x_i}$) to each vertex that represent a clause that contains it
5. add edges between two consecutive variables  $(x_1,x_2),(x_2,x_3),...,(x_n,x_1)$

In particular, rule 5 builds a "backbone" that splits the clauses in two distinct regions.

**[Planar 1-in-3 SAT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-in-three_3SAT)** is NP-complete, too.

> But for planar 1-in-3 SAT are the planarity conditions defined in the same way as in Planar 3SAT ? In particular, can we assume that there is a backbone that links the variables $(x_i,x_{i+1})$  ?

Comment: Just in case if anyone would be looking for the paper where they show hardness of **Planar 1-in-3SAT** (less stronger version). Here is a link: http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?doid=1137856.1137859 From their proof one can see that the "backbone" requirement is easily met.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes you can. Actually you can even show that something stronger is true. The problem know as **Positive Planar 1-in-3-SAT** is NP-complete as shown by [Mulzer and Rote](http://arxiv.org/pdf/cs/0601002v3.pdf).

In this version of 1-in-3-SAT, you require for every input formula that

- you have three variables per clause, none of them negated
- the graph of the formula is planar, even if you add the "backbone" between the variable vertices

The reduction is from **Planar 3-SAT**.